# Conditional Formatting Google Sheet based on a CELL value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to highlight the cell with a color of a cell (range G24:G90) if it contains a G4 cell value (dynamic). What is the best way for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for us to answer is, when you add samples of what you've tried and what result you get.

Although as much i understood from your short description, you can select those range you mentioned and click on **"Conditional Formatting"** and on the **"Formula Rules"** section select **"Custom Formula"** and type something like this based on your requirement:-

```
=$G24=$G$4
```

You can do Formatting Style based on what you like.
You can learn more about advance conditional formatting on this doc :- [Click here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cuse-custom-formulas-with-conditional-formatting)

Comment: This doesn't help. I want to highlight a cell (range G24:G90) containing G4 cell value.

Comment: Share your spreadsheet with edit rights or create a sample spreadsheet if original spreadsheet is having sensitive data, if you can!

Comment: Does it helped you?